# creating a bootable iso for windows

Tags: installation, iso, usb-creator

Hey guys I've been trying for the last 3 hours to work out how to get WinUSB to get this onto my USB but it keeps giving me failed when I try I thought it was permissions so I tried

```
chmod 777
```

but it still wouldn't have it here are the errors any help is appreciated

```
Installation failed !
Exit code: 512
Log:
Formating device...
Mounting...
mount: block device /james/Windows_8.1_Pro_X64_Activated_Final/Windows_8.1_Pro_X64_Activated.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
Copying...
Error occured !
Syncing...
Cleaning...
/usr/bin/winusb: line 78: 14111 Terminated              while true; do
    sleep 0.05; echo 'pulse';
done
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_iso_1389165798_11743'...
umount: /media/winusb_iso_1389165798_11743: device is busy.
        (In some cases useful info about processes that use
         the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
Umounting and removing '/media/winusb_target_1389165798_11743'...
```

Comment: Marking this as a duplicate was stupid. He is not asking about installing winusb, as clearly he already has it, he is asking why he is getting an error... idiots.

Comment: sudo winusb --install win.ISO /dev/sdb1 this works for me.

Answer (score 1):

- Copy the iso file to some other location(Destop or home directory). Then format the usb to FAT32 filesystem using gparted partition Editor.
- Remove the pendrive and then reinsert it.
- It will automatically get mounted, then run `winusb` application.
- Select the copied iso file and create a bootable windows flash drive.