# Can't put windows on a flash drive, even with dd, winusb and unetbootin

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

How can i install my windows 7 iso to a flash drive? dd seemed to have worked, but when i booted it did not work, saying `grub: no such partiton` Which is odd, considering i did not remember installing grub. Does this mean that it's in the iso? or that it's persistent from a previous install, and even formatting won't remove it? Very confused.

Tried: unetbootin, than boot, just boot looped into 'default'

winusb: Failed with error code 512

dd, than boot

format, dd, than boot.

re-downloading the iso from Microsoft store, format, dd

format to ntfs, unetbootin version 494, boot, blinking line on the top left

Comment: Are you serious? Why are you passing it off as a dupe? I've read the article repeatedly and tried all of the methods, and none work for me. I know how to google, if you wanted to screw me over you should say so.

Comment: Try this too: http://askubuntu.com/a/402048/158442

Comment: didn't work....

Comment: If you have problems with moderation please visit META ( http://meta.askubuntu.com/ ) and post a coherent well thought out argument. Editing the question and commenting it NOT the correct way. By the way: "How can i install my windows 7 iso to a flash drive" Windows 7?! Why should AskUbuntu care about W7? Seems OFF TOPIC to me.

Comment: Try a different usb drive.  Sounds like yours might be  dead.

Comment: @Rinzwind: that is not correct. he has a problem with his usbinstaller _on ubuntu_ so it is defenetly on topic. Maybe his answer was somekind confusing, but it is our job to **help** him

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Windows has a unique bootloader that unetbootin - designed for linux - doesn't correctly see and use. Used a friends computer and made a flash drive with rufus with no problem whatsoever. Thanks for being completely useless for three months.